# Magnificpopup detect dom source of picture

Tags: jquery, dom, magnific-popup

Does somebody know a way to get the dom element of the currently shown picture?
I'd like to have a db counter for the number of views of a picture, but when opening pictures in gallery mode I can not find any way to get to the html element which indicates the image and holds an attribute with the id.

I have something like

```
<a href="lightbox.jpg" data-id="1234"><img src="thumb.jpg"></a>
```

Is there a possibility to get the data-id from an event, even if the gallery is open and the user navigated with the arrows?

Comment: Have you checked the events in the docs? http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

Comment: Thank you for this helpful contribution. How could I think there would be a documentation I could look up first...

I did check the docs and there is a change event which is fired, which also has some attributes passed to it, but I don't see any possibility to get the required reference.